# IOS quartz 2d Line Joins and Diamond shapes

Tags: ios7, xcode5, quartz-2d

I'm working on a simple drawing app for ios. The line join doesn't seem to be working for the top (north) point of the diamond.

[image: Example]

Here is the code:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, _currentSize);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, _currentColor.CGColor);
CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, _firstTouch.x, _firstTouch.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, _firstTouch.x + delta, _firstTouch.y + delta);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, _firstTouch.x, _firstTouch.y + (2*delta));
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, _firstTouch.x - delta, _firstTouch.y + delta);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, _firstTouch.x, _firstTouch.y);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
```

`delta` simply represents the length of the sides.

The LineJoin property is working on all points except for the north point (where the path starts and ends.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close the path. Close it.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextClosePath